# Fetch email from the selected Contact in Android APK 25

Tags: android, apk, android-contacts

**Code to get permissions and start Pick Contact Activity**

```
Button chooseContactsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addContactButton);
    chooseContactsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getPermissionToReadUserContacts();
            Intent contacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(contacts, PICK_CONTACTS);
        }
    });
```

**On Activity Result**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACTS) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ContactDataManager contactsManager = new ContactDataManager(this, data);

            try {

                email = contactsManager.getContactEmail();
                EditText e_mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e_mail);
                e_mail.setText(email);

            } catch (ContactDataManager.ContactQueryException e) {
                //Print Exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**getContactEmail Method in Contact Manager class.**

```
public String getContactEmail() throws ContactQueryException
{
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String email = null;
    try
    {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{intent.getData().getLastPathSegment()},
                null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No Email found. and leaving the method.");
        }


    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        throw new ContactQueryException(e.getMessage());
    } finally
    {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }

    return email;
}
```

This doesn't return anything. I have methods for returning name and number and they work fine.
Contact permission is positive.

Comment: Is your `ContactDataManager` Class extending some Android built-in Class ? Try posting your `ContactDataManager` also

Comment: Thanks. Simply Changing the picker intent to 'ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI' worked. This way i could get name number and email too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking the **phone picker** intent (via the `CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` uri in your intent).

You can do one of two things:
(a) change your picker intent to be an **email picker**, and get a specific email in return
(b) change your picker intent to be a **contact picker**, and get the first email found for that contact (if any), by using your `getContactEmail` which is based on a `CONTACT_ID`.

I'd go for option (a), code is:

```
Intent contacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI); // Note the Email!
startActivityForResult(contacts, PICK_CONTACTS);
```

and then:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Get the URI and query the content provider for the EMAIL
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();
        String[] projection = new String[]{CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
        // If the cursor returned is valid, get the email
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String email = cursor.getString(0);
        }
    }
}
```

See more at: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Contacts

Comment: Thanks man. Simply Changing the picker intent to 'ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI' worked. This way i could get name number and email too.

Comment: cool, just heads-up that unlike **phone-picker** / **email-picker** the contact picker doesn't guarantee the selected contact would have any emails/phones, so your code should prepare for this